# Firebase deploy functions Error with Koa in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, koa

I've been trying to deploy firebase functions using Koa in TypeScript.
But I cannot figure out what the problem is. Could anybody help me?

File structure looks like this:

```
├── functions/
│    ├── lib/
│    ├── node_modules/
│    └── src/
│         ├── index.ts
│         ├── .eslintrc.js
│         ├── package.json
│         ├── package-lock.json
│         ├── tsconfig.dev.json
│         └── tsconfig.json
│
├── .firebaserc
└── firebase.json
```

If I just deploy sameple `helloWorld()` in `index.ts` file, then I could deploy function. But for some reason I've tried to deploy Koa server to firebase functions, it keeps failing saying:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    app(asia-northeast3)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:app"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspace/myproj/functions
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c firebase deploy --only functions

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2021-07-27T15_44_39_569Z-debug.log
```

`$ firebase serve --only functions` works fine. But `$ firebase deploy --only functions` doesn't work. And here's my code.

```js
// functions/src/index.ts

import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
import Router from "koa-router"
import Koa from "koa"

export const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

router.get("/", (ctx) => {
    ctx.body = "Okay"
})

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods())

exports.app = functions
    .region("asia-northeast3")
    .https.onRequest(app.callback())
```

```json
// functions/package.json

{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/koa": "^2.13.4",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```json
// functions/tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

```json
// firebase.json

{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance guys!!!

Comment: Can you run `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` and share the output ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thank you so much!! When I tried to print debugged logs and send it to you, I could find the error was coming from `.eslintrc.js` file. Nothing's wrong with the above codes. And I could deploy functions correctly!!!

+ I've added `functions/src/Firebase/firebaseConfig.ts` file which imports `serviceAccount.json` file from local. But it also couldn't run `$ firebase deploy --only functions`. But when I've checked the logs, I could find error was coming from `it cannot find my code`. So I fixed my code that imports `serviceAccount.json` file. All could be solved thanks to you!!